# How to use wget command's --restrict-file-names=OS command to make it suitable for Windows, Linux as well as OSX operating systems?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, cmd, wget

From the help of wget command in Linux Ubuntu:

> **--restrict-file-names=OS**    restrict chars in file names to ones OS allows

In an example I saw on the internet, it was `--restrict-file-names=windows` for windows. But I need the command to be suitable for all Windows as well as Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) as well as OSX operating systems. How do I do that?

Something like

```
wget --restrict-file-names=windows --restrict-file-names=linux --restrict-file-names=osx  URL
```

or something like

```
wget --restrict-file-names=windows,linux,osx  URL
```

Also, how do I know if `linux` and `osx` the correct words/values to use?

Comment: So you do not want to restrict file names at all (mostly)?

Comment: @kabanus By "restrict chars in file names to ones OS allows", what I understood was that it will change file names in a way that it will remove (or replace) the characters which the parent OS does not allow. Now I need to file names to be correct in windows, linux or osx operating systems, so that my program can run successfully in any of those.

Comment: So, based on the `OS` running your script, you want the appropriate restriction? That makes more sense. How are you scripting this (`bash`?)?

Comment: @kabanus Writing a PHP script and running a `shell_exec()` function to run this command..

Comment: "**By default, Wget escapes the characters that are not valid or safe as part of file names on your operating system**, as well as control characters that are typically unprintable. This option is useful for changing these defaults, perhaps because you are downloading to a non-native partition". So unless you are not downloading to non-native partition you do not need to restrict file names by OS. its automatic. Additionally: "**The values ‘unix’ and ‘windows’ are mutually exclusive (one will override the other)**"` Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: @sst Thank you. Can you write that as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted? That will help someone in future